# What exactly is Borderlands the Pre-Sequel

Tags: borderlands-2, borderlands, borderlands-the-pre-sequel, borderlands-series

I've been seeing pre-orders for this however I can't tell exactly what it is, from the title i can some to 2 assumptions

1. It is a game that comes before (pre-) the Sequel to Borderlands (ie. Borderlands 1.5)
2. It is a Sequel set before the titler game (so because it's *Borderlands the Pre-Sequel* and not *Borderlands 2 the Pre-Sequel* it is set before Borderlands)

The second point is more reinforced if the Dev's were just being funny by playing on the word *Prequel*, of cause the Dev's being funny with the name can also explain the first in they wanted a Borderlands 1.5.

So I am wondering, what exactly is Borderlands the Pre-Sequel, is it a Prequel to Borderlands or Borderlands 2

Comment: If #2 would be the case, it would be called a "prequel".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the [Steam store page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/261640/) (emphasis mine):

> Discover the story behind Borderlands 2 villain, Handsome Jack, and
>   his rise to power. **Taking place between the original Borderlands and
>   Borderlands 2**, the Pre-Sequel gives you a whole lotta new gameplay
>   featuring the genre blending fusion of shooter and RPG mechanics that
>   players have come to love.

Your first guess is the correct one. it is before (pre-) the sequel, and after the original Borderlands (After Claptrap's Robot Revolution expansion).

Answer (score 1):

Your first guess was correct. It is (in all bar the title) Borderlands 1.5.

I can't speak for the dev's on this one, sadly because I'm not on the team, but I would say it would be for reasons to do with the storyline. What and why exactly I cannot say.

Comment: Yes, chronologically it can be considered as 1.5. Gameplay wise it is more 2.5 since it takes the improvements from BL2 and adds some stuff to it.

Answer (score 1):

It is the third borderlands title in the series, but chronologically the events take place between borderlands 1 and 2, so it is (arguably) a prequel to borderlands 2.

I say "arguably" because while the events in the playthrough take place between 1 and 2, they are presented as being recalled during a conversation which takes place after BL2.

Comment: The whole game is being told in the conversation? (I'm only ~Lv5). They take place fully after BL2? I had the impression it was somewhere in the middle or before the end. (Finished BL2 but no DLC's besides the pirate one)

Comment: The conversations between Lilth & Co and Athena take place after the events of BL2, but the events which the conversations are about (the playthrough) take place before BL2.

Answer (score 1):

pre-sequel was made to explain Jack's backstory since he never appeared before Borderlands 2. It showcase how he got his power and why he has a mask on his face. Also he is a playable character if you buy him as DLC.

Answer (score -1):

I'm surprised I didn't see this in any of the answers:

The Pre-Sequel is both a prequel and a sequel. It is a prequel to *Borderlands 2* and a sequel to *Borderlands*, hence pre-sequel.

So yes, it is effectively *Borderlands 1.5*, but 'pre-sequel' makes it clearer that it was released after both the others, as the title is aware of both *Borderlands* and *Borderlands 2*, whereas *Borderlands 1.5* could have easily been released before *Borderlands 2*.

Comment: Its not "already in the answers" because its common sense.

Comment: @Timelord64 It's clearly not common sense to the person that asked the question, since this is exactly what they were asking. I'm guessing you downvoted the question also?

Comment: Yes. I dont think this adds anything to the answer, other then duplicating a year old answer. Your speculation on why they chosw the name pre sequel is thoughtful.. but its just speculation. If OP had of truley asked for that, they would not have accepted an alternate answer a year ago.

Comment: @Timelord64 If I had claimed that that last paragraph was the reason they chose the name, that would indeed be speculation. Instead, it's simply an observation. None of the existing answers address the unusual title, instead simply saying that it is between the two, so that's what this adds. Thanks for elaborating on your objections.